# How to get the commits of a branch which is NOT a default branch of a repo?

Tags: rest, github, branch, commit, git-commit

How to get the commits of branch which are not default?
Currently the search commit api is giving only the commits present on default branch.

I have tried the below things. By adding branch name as a query param but not getting anything.
If I remove that query param I get only default branch (i.e. main) commits.

TRIED This: but not getting any output.

https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=repo:test-dai/issue-test+committer-date:1970-01-01..2023-02-14&branch=demo

https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=repo:test-dai/issue-test+committer-date:1970-01-01..2023-02-14+branch=demo

I want commits of a branch which is NOT a default branch.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to send a request to the `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits/{branch_name}` endpoint. It is a linked list, so you will first see the head.

[This question](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/24785) dealt with your problem on GitHub.